# JBoss Developer Studio integration problem with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss, seam

I have worked on .NET web technologies earlier. Now I am starting to work on JBoss Developer Studio 4 GA. I need to create a seam application. I have downloaded seam and during creation of application i am stucked with MySQL JDBC Driver connection.

I have MySQL 5.5 installed and JBoss Dev 4 provides MySQL templates up to 5.1. Could find specific templates over net and manual modification of existing templates doesn't work: Ping Failed. The question may be an easy one, but kindly help me with explanation.

Regards,

Jayesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download a Java JDBC driver for MySQL - you can get one [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).

Comment: @TrueDub I need the driver for MySQL 5.5, which is not available in the link.

Comment: I've used that version of the driver for both MYSQL 4 and MySQL 5, so I suspect it will work fine with 5.5.

Comment: I would not have asked the question if it worked. Any step that you think I may be missing? i am using [this guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.0/pdf/Getting_Started_Guide/JBoss_Developer_Studio-4.0-Getting_Started_Guide-en-US.pdf).

Comment: When you say "MySQL template", what exactly do you mean? I'm guessing (because you didn't say) you're having trouble with the steps on page 45 of that tutorial - if so, have you got the listed JAR file on your machine?

Comment: I am not using Hypersonic connection profile as is given in the tutorial. I am using MySQL 5 connection profile as is given in the welcome/help guide integrated with JBoss Developer Studio 4. The studio has inbuilt MySQL JDBC templates for versions uptill 5.1 and no templates for 5.5. So when i select the JAR file for MySQL 5.5 in the existing template of MySQL JDBC 5.1 template, then the connection does not succeed: Ping Failed. I don't want to roll back to  an older version of MySQL now.....

Comment: and you're sure your other connection parameters are correct? And the database is actually running?

Comment: Yes the database is running. I've run it from the command line and its showing in the task manager too.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can offer to help. I do this regularly through Eclipse (which seems identical, going by the guide), and what I do when asked for a driver on the "Specify a driver template and Definition name" screen is to select "MySQL JDBC Driver 5.1",  then click the "JAR List" tab, and insert the JAR I download from the site I specified above. I then set all the connection parameters and all is well.

Comment: In connection properties there is a database name provided by default:database. Is it because of this? Do you have the database already created in mysql when you start the project or is it create automatically?

Comment: I have it already created - but as far as I know if you remove the database name the ping should succeed.

Comment: Finally I have installed MySql 5.1 :X It works now. Now trying to learn JSF but facing some errors :P

Comment: @TrueDub Kindly check this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450468/404-error-loading-jsf-page

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this question is as much about using the dev studio  as it is about setting this up for MySQL.

Here is what we have done.  Forgive any incorrect terminology. I've gotten this working, but don't fully understand all the pieces.

Make sure to install the JBDC driver in your buildpatch.  We installed ours in the default server lib directory.

You also need a datasource file in the deploy directory.  The seam generator will create one and it looks something like project-ds.xml. It will by default show up in your ear project in the resources folder.

It is not always deployed by default. Make sure it is in the deploy folder of the server. If you can't figure out how to deploy it in JBDS, just copy it in there manually.

You may find it useful to tail the server.log file while you install that folder. You will see the datasource get bound to a jndi name.

Here is an example datasource (in ds.xml)

```
    <datasources>
      <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>contactsDatasource</jndi-name>
      <use-java-context>true</use-java-context>
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://nmstdb-test.ba.ssa.gov:3306/contacts</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
      <user-name>xxxxxx</user-name>
      <password>xxxxxxx</password>
    </local-tx-datasource>
```

The ejb project will have a an ejbModule/META-INF folder that contains a persistence.xml file.  Make sure the jndi-name defined in project-ds.xml matches the jta-data-source defined in persistence.xml.

Make sure hibernate.show_sql (in persistence.xml) is set to true so you can see the query output in the log.

Here is an example persistence.xml file

```
    <persistence-unit name="contacts">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/contactsDatasource</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="contacts"/>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="contacts"/>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/contactsEntityManagerFactory"/>
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Make sure you are using the correct dialect. If you are not using the InnoDB engine, google the correct dialect.

Make sure the value of jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name defined in persistence.xml matches the persistence-unit-jndi-name as defined in the  WebContent/WEB-INF/components.xml.

```
       <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true"
                  persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/contactsEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

Don't forget to check the Problem view to help you discover/fix any compile/syntax type problems.

These are more or less the things you need to look at to get this going.

Comment: Didn't work. I've downgraded to MySQL 5.1 and now the connection works. Thanks for the explanation though!! UpVote :)

Comment: I hope it will help other people even if it was overkill for you. :-)

Comment: [chk it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453362/jsf-project-error-in-jboss-developer-studio)